Laravel Backpack: Use CRUD controller with out a model
Im writing an application with laravel / backpack that allows users to create a custom SQL query to run against a different data.
This database does not contain and laravel or model data, the idea is this could be any database.
I have created the query builder ect using standard crud's which all work fine, however I have the data that is return by this custom query and i want to use it in a list view similar to the way backpack displays standard models.
Is this something that is supported or do i need to look at overriding the backpack blade views?
I have been able to modify the query in the crud to return the correct data but the crud views throw multiple errors.
If someone is able to point me in the right direction that would be great.
thanks!


I have been able to modify the query in the crud to return the correct data but the crud views throw multiple errors.

Can you share the code to understand what exactly you are trying to do?
I'm assuming that You want to display some calculated values, not stored values.
For such needs, I use model_function and model_function_attribute columns. For some cases, closure is also fine.
OR if it is completely different. You can try calebporzio/sushi
